# Am I missing an obvious alternative to a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm working on a small piece of software which is designed for some special Windows based kiosk devices. It listens for certain keystrokes/commands using a driver, intercepts them and performs certain actions.

At the minute, I've got my Proof of Concept working great. I can either run it as a console application in the background, or I've also built it as a Windows Service. The Windows Service is really effective and is working well, but a colleague has hinted that it'd be good to be able to do tasks based on what user application/window is active - something I can't do (legitimately) from a Windows service because it can't enumerate user applications.

The obvious solution would be to simply run it in the background - no drama there, except these kiosks use a custom Windows shell (Deployed using Group Policy). Because of this, the normal explorer Run keys don't initialise. I'm now at a loss on how to make my software autorun in this scenario?

Alternatively, if someone has a workaround for enumerating active windows and such for a specific user from a Windows service I'd be interested in that. NB: I don't need to actually do anything TO the desktop, just read data.

Comment: Why can't the custom Windows shell run your program?

Comment: Do you mean Windows Registry run key? There is a lot of other ways to auto-run a program - just look at Autoruns program http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx May be one of them is OK for you?

Comment: so what task do you want to implement? active applications (if you develop them as well) could also communicate with your windows service. Your story almost sounds like one of those 'but can it make coffee too' requirements. don't design for requirements that arn't in scope any time soon

Comment: @ZippyV It just simply doesn't have that ability - it's not an in-house app.

Comment: @Batavia Sorry, but "Don't bother implementing this feature" is not a particularly helpful comment. I know my app can do what I designed it for, but I'd be interested to explore this as a possibility.

Comment: i'm not saying dont bother. i'm asking what is the real requirement. maybe your active windows could actively send messages over a service bus or maybe you should write a 2nd app to deal just with the issue of enumerating active windows (and possibly then use a message bus to cummunicate this info to your service if you really need it there)

Comment: @Batavia Yep, I could certainly do that *but*, it puts me in the same position - how do I get the second application to automatically launch?

Comment: You could have a service running plus one process per session that communicates with the service. This per-session process would do as little as possible. Would that design help you?

Comment: @usr That design is fine and I get it, what I'm mainly stuck on is the best way to launch this per-session process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Vista and above won't let a service interact with desktop apps at all, part of the new focus on security in the OS. I have something similar (in spirit) that I developed for an application system, which enumerates windows looking for a specific legacy app then sends some messages to it (all very much above-board, no other way to automate the creaky old app). I just launch it as a system-tray app when people log on, using Group Policy. But I don't have the issue of a custom Windows shell that you're apparently dealing with.  Good luck!

So, userinit (`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\`) probably isn't a particularly bad place to do this, but there should be an alternative or two. It's actually a little silly (if you ask me) how many Autorun locations have cropped up in Windows over the years.

The following is largely copied from http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-program-automatic-startup-locations/, with an update or two. I figured it might be handy here, too, and who knows what will remain live on the web forever (or not)?

Other Autorun locations include the following in order:

**Boot device drivers**

Hardware related.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

Windows does some housecleaning then starts Winlogon, which starts the service control manager, which starts services and drivers.

**Services**

The SCM launches services and drivers that are marked with a Start value of 2.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

**RunServicesOnce**

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
```

**RunServices**

HKLM/.../RunOnce entries won't run until these finish starting.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
```

**** The logon prompt is shown, user logs on, then auto-start processing continues.**

**Notify** runs programs in response to events, including logon, logoff, startup, shutdown, startscreensaver, stopscreensaver. Malware often uses this key to start itself.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify
```

**UserInit** specifies programs that should be launched immediately after a user logs on, takes a comma-separated list of programs. The default userinit.exe program loads your profile. Also a common key for malware to use.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Userinit
```

**Shell** contains a comma-separated list of programs that userinit.exe will launch. The default shell is explorer.exe. First the program(s) in HKCU are launched, then the ones in HKLM.

```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

**** The rest of the Autostart locations are processed now...**

**RunOnce (HKLM)** Primarily intended for setup programs, deleted by the OS after the first run if the path is preceded by an exclamation point (!), else deleted before the program runs. These programs are started synchronously in an undefined order, so they must all complete before the HKLM/.../Run, HKCU/.../Run, HKCU/.../RunOnce and Startup folders can be loaded. These keys are ignored when booting in safe mode.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
```

**Run** Most common startup locations for standard programs to autorun from, ignored in Safe Mode unless prefixed with an asterisk (*).

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

**Startup Folder (All Users)**

Win7 and up `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

Win XP/2K `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

**Startup Folder (Per User)**

Win7 and up `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Win XP/2K `%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

**RunOnce (HKCU)** intended primarily for setup programs, same semantics as the HKLM RunOnce key (above).

```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

**Explorer Run** generally used to run programs as per policy configuration.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
```

**Load Key** deprecated, not commonly used anymore.

```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\load
```

**AppInit_DLLs** this registry value contains a list of dlls that will be loaded when user32.dll is loaded. Many programs load user32.dll, so anything listed here gets loaded into all of those programs, as well. Used by malware.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
```

**ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad** similar to the Run key, but points to a registered CLSID InProcServer value. Files listed under this key are automatically loaded by Explorer when the computer starts, early in the startup process.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ShellServiceObjectDelayLoad
```

**SharedTaskScheduler** Files listed here run automatically when you start Windows.

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
```

Other potential autostart locations, depending on the OS:

1. c:\autoexec.bat
2. c:\config.sys
   3 . %WINDIR%\wininit.ini - Usually used by setup programs to have a file run once and then get deleted.
3. %WINDIR%\winstart.bat
4. %WINDIR%\win.ini - [windows] "load"
5. %WINDIR%\win.ini - [windows] "run"
6. %WINDIR%\system.ini - [boot] "shell"
7. %WINDIR%\system.ini - [boot] "scrnsave.exe"
8. %WINDIR%\dosstart.bat - Used in Win95 or 98 when you select the "Restart in MS-DOS mode" in the shutdown menu.
9. %WINDIR%\system\autoexec.nt
10. %WINDIR%\system\config.nt

Comment: Winlogon\Notify [doesn't work after Windows Server 2003](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721961%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the end result I want by adding my application to the UserInit registry key:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\
>
> Userinit c:\windows\system32\userinit.exe,c:\myapp\myapp.exe

This works great, but does seem incredibly hacky and I'd love alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows Service is the best option and since services are isolated in Session 0, you can have this service starts another exe upon user logon, by calling `[CreateProcessAsUser][1]`. In fact, the service executable can call itself with a parameter indicating that it is invoked as a user and therefore all User Interface parts (which normally won't work from Session 0), will be enabled.